# Storing a Set in a variable by calling a Java function in drools

Tags: java, function, variables, call, drools

I want to call a java function (abstract: `getSet(List<object>)`) that determines a set and takes that set in the when part of a drools rule (`$variable`).

The Java function is functional and will also be run through.

Unfortunately, I don't know how I can accept this set from a Drools rule and store it in a variable (`$variable`). Here is an abstract rule example. Unfortunately, the variable `$variable` is empty and cannot be used as desired.

Note: `GetSetOfSomething` is a helper function returning a Set. This helper function returns correct results. `listOfObjcts` is also filled correctly.

```java
import com.example.ClassName();
import com.example.more.ObjectThings();


rule "Example"
   when
      $object: ClassName();
      $listOfObjcts: Set()
          from collect( ObjectThings() from GetSetOfSomething($object));

      // Call up and save the desired set. $variable is empty.
      $variable: Set() from $object.getSet($listOfObjcts); 
      // An inelegant way to get the set is:
      $set: Set() from collect( String() from $object.getSet($listObjects));
      // This string contains the desired set as String.
      $string: String() from String.join(",", $object.getSet($listOfObjcts));
   then
      System.out.println("List of objects: " + $variable);
end
```

Here is the definition of `getSet(List<object>)`:

```java
public Set<String> getSet(List<Something> items) {
    if (items == null) {
        return emptySet();
    }

    Set<String> nameList = new HashSet<>();
    for (Something item : items) {
        nameList.add(item.getName());
    }
    return nameList;
}
```

Comment: if the "variable is empty and cannot be used as desired" then something is going wrong with your `getSet()` call because the rule as you described is correct. What is `$object` and `$listOfObjcts`?

Comment: I agree with you. I don't think you can just accept the set after the function call `$object.getSet($listOfObjcts)`. I've expanded my post to answer your questions. Does anyone have an elegant and simple solution here? @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas

Comment: Does it work if you use `HashSet() from` (or some other concrete type?) I vaguely recall once having an issue like that with List, where you couldn't use the interface like this..

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work with HashSet either. I once tried to output the results of getSet as a string. That worked. I did it that way: `$string: String() from String.join(",", $object.getSet($listOfObjcts));`. @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas

Comment: I know found a way to get the results. But to be honest it is not elegant and short. `$set: Set() from collect( String() from $object.getSet($listObjects));`. Is there a better way?

Comment: It's going to come down to how this `getSet` method is defined.

Comment: I added the definition above. @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas

Comment: Any suggestions? I'm open to any help.